# Integrate AWS Secrets in application Properties, Spring Boot application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager

I have Secrets created in AWS secret manager as Key value pair for OAuth2 clientId and secrets. How can I embed this into application properties? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible ways to do the integration.
I've barely touched the AWS infra so can't really comment on that. I've found this page: [the official amazon documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/manage-credentials-using-aws-secrets-manager.html) However it doesn't really explain the best way to integrate the call from the spring boot standpoint, it just shows how to retrieve the data from the secret manager.

One way to do the integration like this is to make a call to the AWS secret manager before the spring boot application even starts (in the main method):

Schematically it looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApp {

   public static void main(String [] args) {
     // Call SecurityManager here and obtain all the required credential
     // then define system properties so that they'll be able to override the defaults:
     System.setProperty("whateverSecret", <I've_got_the_value_from_AWS_Security_Manager>");
     System.setProperty(...) // other properties
     SprintApplication.run(MySpringBootApp.class);
   }
}
```

If your setup is more advanced and you're using spring cloud, it provides some sort of integration with aws secrets manager. See [documentation of spring cloud](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.1.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-aws.html#_integrating_your_spring_cloud_application_with_the_aws_secrets_manager)

Also, [here](https://blog.usejournal.com/aws-secret-manager-service-as-application-properties-with-spring-boot-f46fe6bd44f7) you can find an example of such an integration

Answer (score 0):

To capture an AWS Secrets value from AWS Secrets Manager in a Spring BOOT App, use the Secrets Manager Java API V2. You will find examples in the AWS Java Developer Guide here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-secretsmanager.html

In the [Java V2 Github repo](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases), you will find examples of using various AWS Java V2 APIs within Spring Boot apps. You can use a V2 Service Client to make calls to AWS Services.

(the other thread shows some ways to hook into application properties)